# Ubuntu sound is locked at a certain level 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound

I have sound, but the problem is that I can't lower it or raise the sound, I'm stuck at a certain sound level. I don't have this issue with the guest profile though. None of my short-cuts work on it, they're usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>F11</kbd>or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F12</kbd> . 
    Thank you cbhihe, I found out from the information you've given me is that my sound system is not recognizing my speakers as an output, but for some reason I can still manually control the sound using ALSA.

Ran the groups command and got the following;
(myIDhere) adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare

I ran the command suggested, sudo adduser `id -un` audio(with my ID) and got; 
The user `IDHere' is already a member of`audio'.

I've been using alsa to change my sound manually but my shortcuts still aren't working.

Comment: Did you ever solve that pbm ?

Answer (score 0):

Something maybe broken in your `pulseaudio` package install (assuming you use *PulseAudio* ... and since that package has a *huge* number of reverse dependencies, better than removing and installing it again (1), did you try (from terminal - CTRL+ALT+T):

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall pulseaudio
```

See if that solves yr pbm. To go a little beyond the scope of yr question, but respecting the spirit of it, check out [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/03/install-pulseaudio-with-built-in-system.html), the PulseAudio equalizer, available for 14.04, I find particularly useful in relation to sound control. I think (from the sound of yr user name - pun intended) that it might prove useful to a gamer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I am not sure if the solution applies to you but at least it is very easy to check it out.

In my case, for some reason I was not in the "audio" group. To check it out, you simply execute the "groups" command and it will print out all the groups you are in.

If the "audio" group is printed out that means that you are added in the "audio" group so that wasn't your problem after all and this solution doesn't apply to you.

If the "audio" group is not printed  out that means that you are not added in the "audio" group and you need to do it manually. For that, you simply enter this command:

```
sudo adduser `id -un` audio
```

The "id -un" is simply your name. You can equally run "sudo adduser yourname audio"